# Why use ::tsvector when you have to_tsvector in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Why  use  ::tsvector when you have  to_tsvector in Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Just for convenience. In Postgres, you can define your own unary or binary operator or casting rule, and when you define it, you must  provide a corresponding 1- or 2-argument function.

At the same time, `to_tsvector(..)` function is overloaded -- it can be 1-argument, or 2-argument function, and in the latter case it is possible to explicitly specify FTS configuration (sometimes it's useful to have multiple configurations). In case of 1-argument function, or `::tsvector`, the default configuration (see `show default_text_search_config;`) will be taken.